# How to approach expanding the deck a little bit to make room for a grill?

Tags: deck

We're always moving the grill around because it's in the way when not in use. I'd like to find a permanent home for it and this location would be perfect if I could easily expand the deck a little.

The idea would be just to remove the railing, extend the deck out about 2' and put the railing back I don't want additional footings so I'm hoping to accomplish this with just some joist hangers off the current beams.

Thoughts on how best to achieve this?

[image]

[image]

[image: Under the deck and stairs]

[image]

Comment: Also, how to you intend to deal with the railing in front of the window?

Comment: There are systems to hang the grill over the railing.  You'd need to solve some issues like not dripping hot fat onto people below, but those issues are easier to solve than extending the actual deck in a way that has to support people.

Comment: I was going to set the new joists on top of the existing joists where the stair landing goes down and run it across to the beam with a hanger so it's the same height as the upper part of the deck.

Good call on the window, we didn't think of this because we don't open those. Maybe we won't bring it all the way to the house and stop short so it can open.

Comment: That's a gain of what, 6"? I'd be dropping a post at the bottom of the stairs and extending the deck _past_ the window.